# Getting Facebook posts from public pages depending on a query

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all posts from Facebook depending on a given query, I am trying to test the following code to get all posts that may contain Facebook word.

```
import json
params = (
    ('q', 'Facebook '),
    ('fields', 'id,name,location,link '),
    ('access_token', 'app_ID|app_secret'),
)

response = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/pages/search', params=params)

print (response.content)
```

in this my case is required only APP ID and APP secret, it is giving me the following error message

```
b'{"error":{"message":"(#10) This endpoint requires the \'pages_read_engagement\' permission or the \'Page Public Content Access\' feature or the \'Page Public Metadata Access\' feature. Refer to https:\\/\\/developers.facebook.com\\/docs\\/apps\\/review\\/login-permissions#manage-pages, https:\\/\\/developers.facebook.com\\/docs\\/apps\\/review\\/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https:\\/\\/developers.facebook.com\\/docs\\/apps\\/review\\/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"A6KWxGkYQjzJn8dAMwf3Zh3"}}'
```

Our App Permissions:
pages_show_list,
pages_read_engagement,
pages_read_user_content,

Where in the following links show that either Page Public Content Access or Page Public Metadata Access refers to pages_read_engagement permission and pages_read_user_content permission
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-metadata-access/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access/

Comment: _"Our App Permissions:"_ - app tokens don't encompass any permissions. To make this request using your app token, you would need one of the two mentioned features approved for your app first. The alternative is to make the request using the user token of a page admin, resp. a page token.

Comment: @CBroe I have tried to test another application with app token that does not encompass any permission, the same message error occurred. Can you explain to me how we can get permissions to access public posts from Facebook without the admin's request of the page?

Comment: You would need the Page Public Content Access feature approved for your app. But whether you would get it, depends on what you want to do with the data - because according to docs, the only currently allowed usage is to "provide competitive benchmark analysis."

Comment: @CBroe yes that's why my app has user token that provides both pages_read_engagement permission and pages_read_user_content permission to obtain Page Public Content Access feature. I really did not find any other way to get Page Public Content Access feature except the user token method. Is there any other methods which we can process to get that feature?

Comment: This has nothing to do with user permissions. You need to submit your app for review, and ask them to grant you access to this feature.

Comment: @CBroe ok, finally! I have spent 4 days solving this problem by using the user token. I really appreciate your help and efforts. Thank you